# Login Info Page Not Redirecting

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am having trouble redirecting my code to another page after a correct username/password has been submitted. After I enter the username/password and hit submit, the page does not redirect.

The page just reloads and clears the field inputs (even though it's a sticky form), and stays at the same page, except the URL adds `?submit=Submit` to the end of the URL..

I am not getting any mysql errors - the database is connecting fine at the query that matches the row with the username/password combo seems to  be going through.

It should be looping through the database, checking if the username/password combo exists, and redirecting to the specified page. I'm not sure what I'm not seeing / missing here that keeps the page from redirecting. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

PHP:

```
<?php
        define('DB_LOCATION', 'x');
        define('DB_USERNAME', 'x');
        define('DB_PASS', 'x');
        define('DB_NAME', 'x');

        $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_LOCATION, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASS, DB_NAME)
            or die('Error connecting to database');

    $error_message= "";

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $user_name = $_POST['user'];
        $user_password= $_POST['pass'];


        // ADD QUERY TO CHECK IF USER/PASS COMBO IS CORRECT
        if(!empty($user_name) && !empty($user_password)) {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE username='$user_name' and password='$user_password'";

        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
            or die ('Error querying username/password request');

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {

                $user_name = $row['user'];
                $user_password = $row['pass'];

                header("Location: www.mysite.com ");

            } // end if rows

            else {
                $error_message = "You were not able to log in";
            } // end else


        } // end query


    } // end isset

?>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Login</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/LESSON5/5_Signup_CSS.css">

</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>
<h2>Please login below.</h2>
<h3>Don't have an account? <a href="/LESSON5/2%20-%20CREATE%20AN%20ACCOUNT.php">Create one here.</a></h3>

<div class="formFormat" >  
<div  id="table1">
<form name =loginForm method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER[' PHP_SELF' ];?>">
  <table id="cssTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" id="user" name="user" value="<?php echo $user_name ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td><td><input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" value="<?php echo $user_password ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
      </table>
  </form>
  </div>

  <div id="table2">
  <form>
  <table> 
  <tr>
     <td><input type="submit" name="submit"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td id="createAccount"><a href="/LESSON5/2%20-%20CREATE%20AN%20ACCOUNT.php">Create an account</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $error_message ?></td>
   </tr>

  </table>
</form>
  </form>
  </div>
</div> 

<?php
    mysqli_close($dbc);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `<form>`, just before `<div id="table2">`, and `</form>` as well.

Comment: Thank you! I created two forms to separate the CSS content, mistakenly thinking hitting 'Submit' grabs the values for any input on the page regardless  of whether or not the inputs are in the same <form>.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<form>` and `</form>` just before `<div id="table2">` but i say you create a simple function which handles the redirects like below.

why don't you try something like this which creates a function for the redirect.

```
function Redirect($url, $permanent = false)
{
    header('Location: ' . $url, true, $permanent ? 301 : 302);
    exit();
}

Redirect('Location: www.mysite.com', false);
```